# How to render only those Leaflet layers which are in current map view?

Tags: web-mapping, leaflet

Is it possible to render Leaflet layers which are in current map view so that other layers which are not in that map view doesn't render? I have many polgons (buildings) and it is really slow rendering if they all renders so I thought it would be ok to divide buildings into many shapefiles which will render only in that map view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, splitting your shapefile in many others is not the right direction to go. Openlayers has introduced the [BBoxStrategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) which retrieve data when the map's viewport is changing.

It seems the [leaflet vector layer plugin](http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/) behaves the same way. So,be lazy, and let the JS library doing the job.

If you want to know a bit more on how it works, you will also find a manual implementation on the following page : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/leaflet-js/1xT8aGNLS7c/CNhk4-BP6AoJ

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
   mylayer.clearLayers();
   if (map.hasLayer(mylayer) && map.getZoom() >= 16) {
      var bbox = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
      $.getJSON("fetch-geojson.php?bbox="+bbox, function(data){
         mylayer.addData(data);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Just one more question: that way only those vectors are read from the database, not all? For example, I have shapefile of 100mb, and I want to render only map view vector this way you described, does that mean that all my 100mb is read from the database or not? Thanks

Comment: First, we are not talking anymore of shapefile but geojson file! Secondly, the file has, for sure, to be queried (as a database or an xml file) regarding the desired coordinates/bbox. Please read the `how?` section in that page : http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/. You can also get detail from the author itself I guess.